# Gitlab CI Pipeline fails because of ruby issue (Ruby installed)

Tags: android, gitlab, continuous-integration

I'm trying to setup CI on Gitlab. I've got a problem. Looks like runner is working well but each time I try to run pipeline it fails with following error :

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.4.0 (4b9e985a)
  on local-runner g_SbFiLZ
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on GU33...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Users/xxx/GitLab-Runner/builds/g_SbFiLZ/0/xxx/xxx/.git/
Checking out f4fb6ec9 as main...
git-lfs/2.11.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.14.2; git 48b28d97)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ gem install bundler
gem : The term 'gem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the s
pelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script461193448\script.ps1:225 char:1
+ gem install bundler
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gem:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I have Ruby installed and setup correctly. I can run gem commands locally. Runner is also set locally so I really dont understand the issue. Here's my gitlab-ci.yml :

```
stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - test
  - ui-test

variables:
  LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
  LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"

.setup_bundler: &setup_bundler |
  gem install bundler
  bundle config
  bundle install

.setup: &setup
  - *setup_bundler

prepare_project:
  stage: prepare
  script:
    *setup
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - Gemfile.lock
    paths:
      - vendor
  artifacts:
    name: "Bundle_${CI_BUILD_NAME}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}_${CI_BUILD_ID}"
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - vendor
    when: always
  when: on_success
  tags:
    - android

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane build
  dependencies:
    - prepare_project
  tags:
    - android

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane tests
  dependencies:
    - prepare_project
  tags:
    - android

ui-test:
  stage: ui-test
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane ui_tests
  dependencies:
    - prepare_project
  tags:
    - android
```

Any ideas, pelase ?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that when you're running `gem` to debug, you're running it with a different user than `gitlab-runner`, which is the default gitlab-runner user. Check the `PATH` setup of your gitlab-runner user, and ensure that `gem` is on the path.

Comment: You mean check PATH in my env variables ? I added Ruby there - works well.

Comment: Yes, in specifically in the environment variables for your `gitlab-runner` user (which is the user the running uses by default, if you've specified a different user, set PATH for that user too). It sounds like you've got it working though, which is good!